# Delete all ocurrences of substring in minimal steps

Tags: string

I want to find the minimum number of deletions I need to make in order for a substring to no longer appear in a given string. Both the string and substring are composed of only lower case letters.

For example, for string "recorerecore" and substring "recore" I would need 2 deletions.

For string "recorecore" and substring "recore" I would need only 1.

For string "recorecorecorecore" and substring "recore" I would need 2, either the first and third or the second and fourth.

For string "rerecorecore" I would need to take out 1, the second occurrence, as taking the first out would lead to having recore again.

I only can think of the brute force solution which involves actually deleting in every combination possible and finding the minimum, but this takes too long.

Does anyone know a way to do this faster?

Comment: Any is fine. If possible C++ or Java.

Answer (score 0):

recursively Boyer–Moore the string with the substring  and delete as you find them

Comment: Isn't that still O(n^2) in the worst case?

Comment: well its faster than brute force...and bonus points for recursion ;) however it will leave you with an empty string in "rerecorecore"...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, I don't want that, I want it to delete the second occurrence so it only deletes one, and gets "rerecore".